# Does jcs JDBC Disk Cache works with postgres?

Tags: java, jdbc, jcs, jdbc-postgres

Does jcs JDBC Disk Cache works with postgres?
I saw in jcs documetation that jcs JDBC Disk Cache is supported with Oracle,MySQL and hsql, since its jdbc, does it support postgres?
If yes does it support ssl enabled database connection?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it worked, when i tested. But if anyone has observed any issues with jcs with postgres, let me know.